# Hiding download links in HTML

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I am offering a pdf document in the form of a download from my website via a landing page.

I want to hide the URL/link that displays in the address bar and when i hover over the download button on the web page so that the link cant be shared.

What is the best way to do this? Please explain carefully.

Thanks

Comment: Depends, what language are you using? Plain HTML or a Server side language (PHP, ASP, etc)?

Comment: for this i am using, HTML

Comment: Ok, I think you should be using a server side language for that part, like PHP. I can write it in PHP if you want ti that way

Comment: ok yes php would be great, anything that works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you cannot do that with plain HTML. You can use all kind of tricks but they can be a problem to the user experience, you are to use a server side language.

What you can do is create a php page, name it the way you want (let's say `download.php`), and link to that one. The page should be something like this:

```
// Path to the file
$path = '/home/folder/yourfile.pdf';

// This is based on file type of $path, but not always needed    
$mm_type = "application/octet-stream";

//Set headers
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

// Outputs the content of the file
readfile($path); 

exit();
```

This way you just link to your `download.php` page and it downloads/opens the PDF, like so:

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com/download.php">Download</a>
```

**Edited based on `BenjaminC` suggestions**

The other chance you have is to connect this to a database. The database has a table named `downloads_table` and inside you have 2 fields:

1. secret: `char(32)`
2. downloaded: `int(1) dafault 0`

Then you create an `md5` string
    $secret = md5(rand(1000, 9999999));

Place it inside the `secret` field, create the link:

```
 <a href="http://www.somesite.com/download.php?s=ahanlskdhf78asdf87absdfas8d7f6">Download</a>
```

The user receives/sees a link, when pressed you are to edit the first line of the above code to check in the db if `downloaded` field = to 0 than procede to download, otherwise the person sees an error page.
This is so that it can be downloaded only once.

Comment: ok great, thanks for that. So the download link in the html code would therefore be <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/download.php">Download here</a>
?

Comment: That doesn't fix the initial question of the problem : the link to `download.php` would still be visible when hovering the button and will be sharable.
What you just did is kind of obfuscate the true filename in the URL, that's all.

Comment: This seems awfully complicated when you could just load the file's download in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Place this somewhere in the body of the webpage:

And place this somewhere in the webpage:

```
<script>
    function download() {
        document.getElementById("download").src = "/path/to/download";
    }
<script>
```

Then, on the element of the button (In the example of a div) do this in the tag:

```
<div onclick="download()"> </div>
```

However if it's a link you will want to do:

```
<a href="#" onclick="download()"> </a>
```

An  element needs a href to work properly.

Comment: The closing tag should be "</script>" and .src must be replaced by .href and the <a> must have an id like <a id="download" ... >

Comment: Never use an `onclick` on a `<a>` and in this case the `<div>` should be a `<button>`.

So the correct way here is:

`<button type="button" onclick="download()">Download</button>`

Comment: Also in this answer, the path to the file can be revealed by simply looking at the source. Only Mr.Web's answer hides the path from the client.

Answer (score -1):

(Edit)

If in the future, this gets useful for anyone, the functionality can be seen in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aznjr87g/

It downloads 2.1.3 jquery.min.js from google.

(Edit end)

This can be achieved using Html5 's Download attribute.

```
<a href="#" download="path/path/file.dpf">Download PDF</a>
```

If you hover your mouse over that, it simply shows yoursite.com/#

Comment: Ok, but if I open the html (Show Source) I can see the file name, won't I?

Comment: Yes, if you view it with dev tools you can see the url in the download attribute, there is no way to avoid that using plain HTML.

Comment: If you don't want that i would suggest you to use the code provided by Mr.Web ^^

Comment: The value of `download` is the filename, you shouldn't be storing paths in there as the browser will try to download that as the name of the file.